# Where are kernel and initramfs files for systemd-boot?

Tags: arch-linux, boot-loader, uefi, initramfs, systemd-boot

I'm trying to do a fresh install and use `systemd-boot` as the bootloader for my ESP, but in the [install instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-boot#EFI_boot) on step 4 it says:

> Copy your kernel and initramfs onto that ESP.

But where are `vmlinuz-linux` and `initramfs-linux.img` located? I can't find them for the life of me.  Do I need to install `bootctl` before those files are available?  Nothing exists in `/boot` in either my Arch Linux install disk or the partitions that I'm working with

Comment: For the vanilla kernel, those files will be named `vmlinuz-linux` (kernel) and `initramfs-linux.img` (initrd). You should also have a `initramfs-linux-fallback.img`.

Comment: Yeah, I can see the filenames that I'm supposed to copy over in the instructions, but I can't find where they're located

Comment: Have you [pacstrapped base](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide#Install_the_base_packages)?

Comment: I did but I wasn't able to find the files on the partition that I'd strapped to.  Would they be located somewhere in `/usr/src` on that partition?  Am I still able to copy files over to my `/boot` partition after `pacstrap`ping though?  Shouldn't I have all of my partitions set up properly before doing that?

Comment: It sounds like /boot wasn't mounted when you pacstrapped...

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have another go this afternoon after work.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

In the linked Wiki (which does not contain that exact phrase any more), there is a section (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot#Preparing_kernels_for_/EFI/Linux), which applies only, if you want to create such a special kernel. Other than that, the linux kernel is placed in `/boot` whenever you install/update the linux package with `pacman`, i.e. also via `pacstrap`.